# UIView Animation stops working when UICollectionView scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a UIView. I am setting its position in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method in my code:

```
self.displayView.frame =  CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

and on press of a button to display this view the animation is done as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.displayView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}];
```

I also have a UICollectionView on the same page.
The above animation works perfectly until I start scrolling the UICollectionView. If I scroll the UICollectionView and then click the button for the above animation to occur, it does not work. I checked the position of the displayView before and after the animateWithDuration block and it displays the exact same location. (The x and y co-ordinate of the displayView is not changing)
Trying to figure out where I have messed up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to remove `self.displayView.frame` in  `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? And what happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called numerous times during the scrolling of the `UICollectionView`. Thus, it will try to re-position your view back to:

```
self.displayView.frame =  CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Instead, try setting the above within `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.displayView.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

As test, I set up a button, which, upon being clicked, will animate a view like the one you have of the same `frame` and `position` as you specified.

The view moves in, regardless of the scrolling state of the `UICollectionView`.

I have tried, also, to set up a tap gesture recognizer on the animated view itself to animate it back to its post-animation `frame` and `position` even when the `UICollectionView` is being scrolled:

```
self.displayView.frame =  CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

And the animation was not affected by the scrolling, because the setting of `frame` was moved to `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem today while trying to do a bouncing animation:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
               delay: 0,
               options: [.autoreverse, .repeat],
               animations: { self.bouncingHeart.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2) },
               completion: nil)
```

After scrolling it simply did not animate anymore. The solution was to reset the properties which changed inside the `animations` block when `prepareForResure` is called:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    bouncingHeart.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
}
```

### Why does this happen?

No animation will occur if you animate a property which already reached its *target value*. You can test this by creating a `UIView` with `alpha = 1`, then trying to animate `alpha = 1` - the completion block will be executed instantly.